# Merging and retrieving children using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a model that looks like this:

```
A -- Many-toMany --> B -- Many-toMany --> C
```

Both `A` and `B` have the CascadeType of `All` and FetchType of `Lazy`.

When I make the following call:

```
A mergedA = (A) session.merge(a);
```

The `mergedA` has the collection of `B` objects resolved.  `B` however does not have its collection of `C` objects resolved.

If I make the following call:

```
B mergedB = (B) session.merge(b);
```

The `mergedB` has the collection of `C` objects resolved.

If both `A` and `B` have the CascadeType of `All`, why does the collections of `C` objects not get resolved for the collection of `B`s when I call `session.merge(a);`?

Comment: How the `FetchType` is playing any role here?

Comment: I didn't think it would have played a role.  I just made a note of it just in case someone wanted more info about the annotations/attributes I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because, it does it for the single step deep in the object graph and `C` is at the second step. Thus, it did just for the immediate one.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because cascade has to do with transitive persistence, and nothing to do with lazy vs non lazy.

Transitive persistence as a concept applies to logical operations that you want to 'transit' from parents to children.  So its all about "you deleted a parent, and should that cascade down to children?" -- its about the semantics you want in your object relationships.

lazy vs non lazy is a persistence implementation detail.  So its all about "do I as a persistence layer load this thing now?" -- its about how to optimize the persistence layer.

As a note,  Im wondering if this is a correct application of merge.  Merge is for reattaching a detached object to the session when an object with the same id is already in the session.  Im a  bit surprised that it is loading the children at all.

Comment: I was a bit surprised at first too but then I noticed that MERGE is an option in the CascadeType enum.

Comment: yeah, i suspect that since you have cascade all, merge is loading the children to make sure that any potential merges on the children happen

Comment: digiarnie -- take the cascade off and see if merge still loads the children

Comment: Yeah I've tried that and if there is no merge cascade type then the children does not get retrieved (which is expected).  I was just wondering why it didn't merge any deeper.

Comment: @Digiarnie, I think its because the children were not in the session when the merge was called.  It merged the parent.  If the children were in the session, they would have been merged.